# How to change innerHTML with ag-grid processRowPostCreate?

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

I read that this gridoption callback allows users to process the rows, which is to add attributes.

I like to add my own angular attributes [myCustomAttribute] = "XXXX" into the ag-grid rows but my code dont seems to work.

```
processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
                if (params) {
                    const eRow = params.eRow;
                    console.dir(eRow); // no error
                    console.log(eRow.innerHTML); // innerHTML undefined
                }
            }
```

It complains that innerHTML is undefined and I couldnt access it. But console.dir(eRow) did show there is an innerHTML in that object.

How can we change the innerHTML with ag-grid 'processRowPostCreate'?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to add an attribute to each row using the processRowPostCreate method as follows:

```
processRowPostCreate<RowData>(args: ProcessRowParams<RowData>) {
  const { node,  eRow} = args;
   eRow.setAttribute('level', `${node.level}`)
}
```

then, added this method to grid options:

```
<AgGridReact<Row>
   ...,
   processRowPostCreate={processRowPostCreate}
/>
```

Using this function you can do almost anything with the row